# "You have my word" or "You have my words"?

Tags: nouns, singular-vs-plural

Why it is ""You have my **word**" rather than "You have my **words**"?"

Comment: Could you explain why you feel "words" could have that meaning? Maybe by showing what you found in a dictionary?

Answer (score 3):

In his renowned A Dictionary of Modern English Usage, H. W. Fowler defined **an idiomatic expression** as one that is “natural for a normal Englishman to say or write.” He went on to say that idiomatic English is not necessarily grammatical or ungrammatical. (**[Mark my words](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mark+my+words)**, that man is to be trusted.)

**You have my word** is idiomatic to say.

of (one's) [word](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/My+Word):

> Displaying personal dependability: *a woman of her word.*
>
> An assurance or promise; sworn intention: *She has kept her word*.

(MW)

'You have my word' derives from the [chivalric code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chivalry). One would literally have to stake their word, synonymous with their honor, upon completing whatever was agreed upon.

**['You have my word/I give you my word/take my word for it'.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Take+my+word+for+it)**

Answer (score 1):

To make this simple, consider the following.

"You have my word" connotes a promise or vow.

"You have my words" would mean that they have said something other than a promise.